# Can the Pine plotshape function be used to plot a shape over a candle body?

Tags: pine-script, trading

I'm just getting into Pine and I'm trying to figure out how to use **plotshape** to place a shape "on top of" a bar using **location.absolute**. ie at the top UI layer.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about. The script plots a circle at a bollinger band touch.

[image]

You'll notice that the wicks draw on top of the circle shape. However, since they are thin you can still see the shape beneath them. The 2nd (middle) circle is clipped by the bar body. In the case where the entire body extends beyond the bollinger band the circle shape is entirely covered.

I want to be able to draw the shape "on top of" the candle. So that it is always visible.

Is this possible? It seems to always draw behind the bar body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this one out. Thanks to @ja88a on the Pine Script forum.

From the Object Tree drag the script above the chart element. Optionally from the Object Tree right-click on the script object and select "Visual Order > Bring to Front"